# Нахождение кубического корня большого числа

Tags: python, математика

Как вычислить кубический корень числа `33307028807218380701173040920772273133747152666242396962200448019852017733098`?

Возможно кто-то знает какой-либо обобщённый алгоритм (на Питоне, например) для нахождения кубического корня?

Comment: так не подойдет: `33307028807218380701173040920772273133747152666242396962200448019852017733098**(1/3)` ?

Comment: неа) так не подходит

Comment: А по условиям задачи должно быть решение в целых числах?

Comment: @AlexTitov да, это желательное условие, но необязательное

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если уж очень хочется именно самому и именно в целых числах - то, с понятной точностью :) - например, https://ideone.com/kI8FCb:

```
def icroot(a):
    c = a
    b = 2*c//3+a//(3*c*c)
    while (abs(b-c) >= 1) :
        c = b
        b = 2*c//3+a//(3*c*c)
    return b
```

Метод Ньютона.

Comment: слова/ссылка, на описание почему алгоритм работает,  не помешает¶ Если хочется сохранить загадку, то можно ещё `while a!=b: a, b = newa, newb` синтаксис использовать¶ `abs(b-c)>=1` вместо `b!=c` это к чему?

Comment: @jfs Да я так обрадовался, что сумел на Питоне сваять что-то, что обо всем забыл :)

Comment: плохо связалось, уже [`icroot(1)` падает](https://ideone.com/pRaBGw)

Answer (score 3):

Если деление доступно, то можно использовать [метод Ньютона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F_n-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Если только умножение - попробовать бинарный поиск (в реализации, когда шаг сначала увеличивается, а после превышения нужного результата - уменьшается)